# PvAPI OpenCV built-in code: FPS mismatch and how to use multiple cameras?

Tags: c++, opencv, camera, computer-vision, visual-studio-2015

I have two ***Manta G125B*** cameras (B stands for black that means monochrome). These are ***GigE interface*** cameras, and I am using ***PvAPI C++ application programmer's interface*** to read camera data to my Windows OS laptop by using ***Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2015 IDE***.
Recently I came across Steven Puttemans' github account and there he shared the code **AVT_Manta_opencv_builtin.cpp** in this link:

https://github.com/StevenPuttemans/opencv_tryout_code/blob/master/camera_interfacing/AVT_Manta_opencv_builtin.cpp

I downloaded OpenCV 3.0.0 ***source*** files from
***Itseez github*** page and built all required files by using ***CMake*** (I selected ***use default native compilers*** and ***Visual Studio 14 2015 64*** options after I clicked ***configure*** option as I am using a 64-bit CPU and MVS Community 2015). I selected **WITH_PVAPI** option after ***first configuration*** (actually it was already selected) and I noticed that **PVAPI_INCLUDE_PATH** and **PVAPI_LIBRARY** options are automatically recognized correctly as **C:/Program Files/Allied Vision Technologies/GigESDK/inc-pc** and **C:/Program Files/Allied Vision Technologies/GigESDK/lib-pc/x64/PvAPI.lib**, respectively. I clicked ***configure*** option again, and then clicked ***generate*** option (in the mean time, if I don't unselect **BUILD_PERF_TESTS** and **BUILD_TESTS** options which are already selected after configurations, when I open **OpenCV.sln** and build **ALL_BUILD** and **INSTALL**, Visual Studio shows three errors. I removed the ticks at **BUILD_PERF_TEST** and **BUILD_TESTS** options, and errors are gone).

After building OpenCV from scratch, I made a Visual Studio project and modified Steven Puttemans' code slightly to see real-time camera acquisition from one of my cameras while printing frame number and frame rate on console. Here is my code:

```
int main()
{
    Mat frame, imgResized;
    double f = 0.4; /* f is a scalar in [0-1] range that scales the raw image. Output image is displayed in the screen. */
    DWORD timeStart, timeEnd; // these variables are used for computing fps and avg_fps.
    double fps = 1.0; // frame per second
    double sum_fps(0.);
    double avg_fps(0.); // average fps
    int frameCount = 0;
    VideoCapture camera(0 + CV_CAP_PVAPI); /* open the default camera; VideoCapture is class, camera is object. */
    if (!camera.isOpened())
    {
        cerr << "Cannot open the camera." << endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    double rows = camera.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT); /* Height of the frames in the video stream. */
    double cols = camera.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH); /* Width of the frames in the video stream. */
    double exposure = camera.get(CV_CAP_PROP_EXPOSURE);
    cout << "Exposure value of the camera at the beginning is " << exposure << endl;
    double exposureTimeInSecond = 0.02; /* As exposureTimeInSecond variable decreases, fps should increase */
    exposure = exposureTimeInSecond * 1000000; /* esposure time in us */
    camera.set(CV_CAP_PROP_EXPOSURE, exposure);
    double frameRate; /* built-in fps */
    cout << "Frame size of the camera is " << cols << "x" << rows << "." << endl;
    cout << "Exposure value of the camera is set to " << exposure << endl;
    char* winname = "Manta Camera";
    namedWindow(winname, WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    cout << "Press ESC to terminate default camera." << endl;

    while (true)
    {
        timeStart = GetTickCount();
        camera >> frame;
        frameCount++;
        frameRate = camera.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FPS); /* Built-in frame rate in Hz. */
        /* resize() built-in function is in imgproc main module, in Geometric Image Transformations module. I resize the image by f (where f is a scalar in [0-1] range) for display. */
        resize(frame, imgResized, Size(), f, f, INTER_LINEAR); /* void cv::resize(InputArray src, OutputArray dst, Size dsize, double fx = 0, double fy = 0, int interpolation = INTER_LINEAR) */
        imshow(winname, imgResized);
        moveWindow(winname, 980, 50);
        int key = waitKey(10);
        if (key == VK_ESCAPE)
        {
            destroyWindow(winname);
            break;
        }
        /* Calculating FPS in my own way. */
        timeEnd = GetTickCount();
        fps = 1000.0 / (double)(timeEnd - timeStart); /* 1s = 1000ms */
        sum_fps += fps;
        avg_fps = sum_fps / frameCount;
        cout << "FPS = " << frameRate << ", frame #" << frameCount << ", my_fps = " << fps << ", avg_fps = "<< avg_fps << endl;
    }

    cout << "Compiled with OpenCV version " << CV_VERSION << endl; /* thanks to Shervin Emami */
    system("pause");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

and this is the screenshot of the output during real-time acquisition:
[image: My laptop screenshot when the given code is running]

Can someone explain why built-in fps is 30.9? I am pretty sure that real fps in my screen is around 15-16 Hz because I computed time between two different frame numbers that I see in my console, and then computed the fps and the result is the same as avg_fps value in console. I also ran SampleViewer.exe file that is in C:\Program Files\Allied Vision Technologies\GigESDK\bin-pc\x64 directory and when I click on "Show camera's attributes" icon, I see StatFrameRate = 30.2 approximately.

My second question is, how can I open the second camera that is connected to network switch? And also, how can I trigger them at the same moment? I examined cap_pvapi.cpp file that is located in source files that I downloaded from Itseez github page, and as far as I understand, the camera's FrameStartTriggerMode is "Freerun." Other options are SyncIn1, SyncIn2, FixedRate and Software. My main camera is left camera and I call the second camera as right camera. What should be the corresponding FrameStartTriggerMode for my left and right cameras?

Answer (score 1):

I am able to open both of the cameras:

[stereo camera real-time acquisition with OpenCV PvAPI built-in option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mZQ44.jpg)

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Windows.h" /* data type DWORD and function GetTickCount() are defined in Windows.h */
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#include <cassert>
#include <ppl.h> // Parallel patterns library, concurrency namespace. Young-Jin uses this, so do I. It's very important; if not used, when images are processed, fps drops dramatically.
#if !defined VK_ESCAPE /* VK stands for virtual key*/
#define VK_ESCAPE 0x1B /* ASCII code for ESC character is 27 */
#endif

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

const unsigned long numberOfCameras = 2;
bool displayImages = true;

int main()
{
    Mat frame[numberOfCameras], imgResized[numberOfCameras];
    double f = 0.4; /* f is a scalar in [0-1] range that scales the raw image. Output image is displayed in the screen. */
    DWORD timeStart, timeEnd; // these variables are used for computing fps and avg_fps.
    double fps = 1.0; // frame per second
    double sum_fps(0.);
    double avg_fps(0.); // average fps
    int frameCount = 0;
    VideoCapture camera[numberOfCameras]; // (0 + CV_CAP_PVAPI); /* open the default camera; VideoCapture is class, camera is object. */
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfCameras; i++)
    {
        camera[i].open(i + CV_CAP_PVAPI);
        if (!camera[i].isOpened())
        {
            cerr << "Cannot open camera " << i << "." << endl;
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
    }
    double rows = camera[0].get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT); /* Height of the frames in the video stream. */
    double cols = camera[0].get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH); /* Width of the frames in the video stream. */
    if (numberOfCameras == 2)
        assert(rows == camera[1].get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT) && cols == camera[0].get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH));
    for (int i = 0; i<numberOfCameras; i++) // initializing monochrome images.
    {
        frame[i] = Mat(Size(cols, rows), CV_8UC1); /* Mat(Size size, int type) */
        resize(frame[i], imgResized[i], Size(0, 0), f, f, INTER_LINEAR);
    }
    /* combo is a combined image consisting of left and right resized images. images are resized in order to be displayed at a smaller region on the screen. */
    Mat combo(Size(imgResized[0].size().width * 2, imgResized[0].size().height), imgResized[0].type()); /* This is the merged image (i.e., side by side) for real-time display. */
    Rect roi[numberOfCameras]; /* roi stands for region of interest. */
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfCameras; i++)
        roi[i] = Rect(0, 0, imgResized[0].cols, imgResized[0].rows);
    /* Setting locations of images coming from different cameras in the combo image. */
    if (numberOfCameras > 1) /* I assume max camera number is 2. */
    {
        roi[1].x = imgResized[0].cols;
        roi[1].y = 0;
    }

    double exposure, exposureTimeInSecond = 0.06; /* As exposureTimeInSecond variable decreases, fps should increase */
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfCameras; i++)
    {
        exposure = camera[i].get(CV_CAP_PROP_EXPOSURE);
        cout << "Exposure value of the camera " << i << " at the beginning is " << exposure << endl;
        exposure = exposureTimeInSecond * 1000000; /* esposure time in us */
        camera[i].set(CV_CAP_PROP_EXPOSURE, exposure);
    } 
    double frameRate[numberOfCameras]; /* built-in fps */
    cout << "Frame size of the camera is " << cols << "x" << rows << "." << endl;
    cout << "Exposure value of both cameras is set to " << exposure << endl;
    char* winname = "real-time image acquisition";
    if (displayImages)
        namedWindow(winname, WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    cout << "Press ESC to terminate real-time acquisition." << endl;

    while (true)
    {
        timeStart = GetTickCount();
        Concurrency::parallel_for((unsigned long)0, numberOfCameras, [&](unsigned long i)
        {
            camera[i] >> frame[i];
            frameRate[i] = camera[i].get(CV_CAP_PROP_FPS); /* Built-in frame rate in Hz. */
            resize(frame[i], imgResized[i], Size(), f, f, INTER_LINEAR); /* void cv::resize(InputArray src, OutputArray dst, Size dsize, double fx = 0, double fy = 0, int interpolation = INTER_LINEAR) */
            imgResized[i].copyTo(combo(roi[i])); /* This is C++ API. */
        });
        frameCount++;
        if (displayImages)
        {
            imshow(winname, combo);
            moveWindow(winname, 780, 50);
        }
        int key = waitKey(10);
        if (key == VK_ESCAPE)
        {
            destroyWindow(winname);
            break;
        }
        /* Calculating FPS in my own way. */
        timeEnd = GetTickCount();
        fps = 1000.0 / (double)(timeEnd - timeStart); /* 1s = 1000ms */
        sum_fps += fps;
        avg_fps = sum_fps / frameCount;
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfCameras; i++)
            cout << "FPScam" << i << "=" << frameRate[i] << " ";
        cout << "frame#" << frameCount << " my_fps=" << fps << " avg_fps=" << avg_fps << endl;
    }

    cout << "Compiled with OpenCV version " << CV_VERSION << endl; /* thanks to Shervin Emami */
    system("pause");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}


// double triggerMode = camera.get(CV_CAP_PROP_PVAPI_FRAMESTARTTRIGGERMODE);
////camera.set(CV_CAP_PROP_PVAPI_FRAMESTARTTRIGGERMODE, 4.0);
//
//if (triggerMode == 0.)
//cout << "Trigger mode is Freerun" << endl;
//else if (triggerMode == 1.0)
//cout << "Trigger mode is SyncIn1" << endl;
//else if (triggerMode == 2.0)
//cout << "Trigger mode is SyncIn2" << endl;
//else if (triggerMode == 3.0)
//cout << "Trigger mode is FixedRate" << endl;
//else if (triggerMode == 4.0)
//cout << "Trigger mode is Software" << endl;
//else
//cout << "There is no trigger mode!!!";
```

But fps is still not the value that I desire.. :(

I also noticed that there exists cap_pvapi.cpp (contributed by Justin G. Eskesen) file that is implicitly used by my code at this subdirectory:
C:\opencv\sources\modules\videoio\src
and when I examined it, I saw that both cameras are set to "Freerun" FrameStartTriggerMode. Original command in PvAPI is:
PvAttrEnumSet(Camera.Handle, "FrameStartTriggerMode", "Freerun");
In my opinion, when using stereo cameras, cameras should be set to "Software" FrameStartTriggerMode. I already have a code that is running in this configuration for my stereo camera setup, but after some time, my console and running application are getting frozen. I tested my code if there memory leak or not and I am quite sure that there is no memory leak.

Average fps is about 16 but sometimes fps becomes low such as 2Hz which is not good. Good side of this code is, it doesn't stop but still not reliable. I am still wondering if it's possible to transfer all images at a fps more than 25. Actually, in my other code that gets frozen after some time (the one that is triggered by "Software" option), if I don't display the images on screen, avg_fps gets close to 27Hz. But it stops and screen gets frozen due to an unknown failure.